# Block API on the basis of payload size

Tags: python, django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

My use case is to block API when incoming payload size (post call) exceeds more than 5mb, how can I do that?
APIs are written in python (Django) and deployed on AWS Beanstalk with a classic load balancer and without AWS API gateway.
I know I can check payload/body size in method implementation but what I want is to block at gateway or load balancer level so that server denies request in the start not penetrate into the code.
Please help me out on this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to block incoming or outgoing requests?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention incoming traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution in wsgi/uwsgi level add **LimitRequestBody** in wsgi.conf.
for more info -- https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html#limiting-request-content

example: -

```
<Directory /opt/python/app/>


LimitRequestBody 5000000

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing that with Django is not a very good choice, as you will have to actually accept the request, parse it, read it, check the size then return the result of DENY
I would suggest you use Nginx as the proxy server before Django, and

````
```http {
...
client_max_body_size 5M;
````

} ```

This helps blocking the request even before it reach the Django server.

Comment: I agree doing in django is not a good solution that's what I mention and we are not using nginx we are using wsgi, if you have any solution around wsgi please let me know thanls

Comment: So you can control the amount of data from environ['wsgi.input'] then check the Content-Length header

Comment: I am new in wsgi can you please elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use [AWS WAF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-chapter.html).

With WAF you can create a rule based on request size ([size constraint rule statement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-type-size-constraint-match.html)). This way you could be rejecting all requests over specific size before they hit your ALB.

It should be noted that WAF **requires application load balancer** in your EB, or CloudFront distribution before it.

Comment: Yes you are right but I am looking a solution at backend/server side perspective not in AWS services.